# FBSDKAppInviteDialog not returning to app

Tags: ios, facebook, safari

I am using the FaceBook SDK to ask my users to invite their friends to download my app:

```
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

With the FaceBook app installed on the device, after the user has invited friends (or cancelled), the user is successfully returned to my app. To ensure this happens, I needed to place this long list in my `info.plist`:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

When the FaceBook app is not installed on the device, I thought this would stop an external call, but it doesn't - the boolean `canShow` still returns true:

```
FBSDKAppInviteDialog *inviteDialog = [[FBSDKAppInviteDialog alloc] init];
    if (inviteDialog.canShow) {
        ...
```

Without the FaceBook app installed, it goes instead to the Safari browser, and opens a window for facebook.com. But after the user invites, or cancels, it doesn't successfully return to my app. Am I missing something in my `info.plist` schemes?

Comment: The showWithContent method is deprecated; is this also happening for the newer methods? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppInviteDialog/

Comment: Any luck with this @coco?

Comment: I actually managed but it only worked with the latest Facebook 4.10. SDK @coco. Note that the 4.10 SDK does not go the the Native FB App but to the web view for any permissions. That is now apparently the standard.